# Remove style `?ver=` from `/wp-admin/upgrade.php`

Tags: filters, security, admin-css

Using `style_loader_src` hook to remove the version query works just fine, but on `/wp-admin/upgrade.php` the version queries won't go away.

Is there a way to also remove the versions strings from the `/wp-admin/upgrade.php` page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning the plugin code into a **must-use plugin** seems to work.

But not exactly what I am looking for tbh.

Comment: Plugins are not active on upgrade.php, so this is the only solution. I can't think of a good reason why you would ever want to do this though. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @JacobPeattie Ah, okay, I see. Was thinking of something like this. I was trying to hide the WordPress version query string. Pentesting with `wpscan` turned out, that the version is discoverable by that particular page.